# Cannot login after installing Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm having a hard time getting Nvidia proprietary drivers to work in ubuntu. After enabling the Nvidia driver, I cannot login, I'll get a black screen and the system reboots after a few seconds.

Because I can't login, I don't know when should I run nvidia-bug-report.sh . Currently, I can login when I prime-select to intel when I go to the recovery mode of ubuntu and reboot after. I ran nvidia-bug-report.sh 2 times, the old one I ran on the recovery mode and the newer one when I login after setting prime-select to intel.

[nvidia-bug-report.old.log.gz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zLzmSoBp0_7rOrwebtSQUQZfsBBr31Qk/view?usp=sharing)

[nvidia-bug-report.log.gz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16BS9EhkOWXTjPbBFI4JKilto3mhvkS_n/view?usp=sharing)

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-27-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620
Nvidia Graphics Processor: GeForce MX150
Nvidia Driver Version: 510.60.02-0ubuntu1
```

Comment: There are problems with Ubuntu and Ubuntu community flavours of version 22.04 and nvidia. What happened with the built-in free graphics driver nouveau? Did it work as is or did you need the boot option `nomodeset`? - An alternative is to run Kubuntu version 20.04.x LTS until the worst problems with drivers for nvidia are solved, maybe in August with the first point release 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: @sudodus I had problems with nouveau, but not like this problem, my laptop couldn't wake from sleep with nouveau. But I had the same issue with 20.04 and 21.04, don't think it's related to the new 22.04. Please tell me if any other information is needed in the question.

Comment: I see. 1. How well or bad is the computer running with the built-in Intel graphics? 2. Did you try some other nvidia graphics driver (other than 510.60.02-0ubuntu1, for example a driver that you get directly from nvidia)? Chances are small, but maybe worth testing anyway.

Comment: 1. I have a dual boot setup with windows 10, everything works fine there, but in Linux, I get some overheating, probably because I'm using only the Intel UHD all the time. 2. I have tested almost all the other versions, and nothing changes. I have also tested different kernels from 5.9 to 5.15, and it didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot help you. I have two older nvidia cards, and they work best with nouveau and Xorg (not proprietary driver, not Wayland), but you have already tested that. Let us hope that someone else knows how to fix the problem with your nvidia chip/card will see your question and help you.